# Success confirmation page not showing after checkout

Tags: magento-1.9

By using cash on delivery it is not redirecting to success or failure page, It is one page checkout, with other online payments it is redirecting well.. but not using cash on delivery

Comment: What happen after clicking on the place order button on the review order step?

Comment: order is placing but not giving confirmation message to customer, so that customer keep clicking on the place order button again and again, so number of sales happpeing with cash on delivery.

Comment: Are you getting a blank white screen? Did you check your php/magento error log?

Comment: probably your `session clear` is disabled in core file or any extension overwriting this.

Comment: @R.S Thanks for reminding to check in error log, it's fixed and working now.

Comment: Please consider adding steps that you took to fix the error as answer and marking that as correct answer to help others.